# mutate data frame to check if data duplicate between two data frame

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have two data frame, this is just a sample , database have approx 1 million of records.
can have name, email, alphanumeric code etc.

```
data1<-data.frame(
  'ID 1' = c(86364,"ARV_2612","AGH_2212","IND_2622","CHG_2622"),
  sector = c(3,3,1,2,5),
  name=c("nhug","hugy","mjuk","ghtr","kuld"),
  'Enternal code'=c(1,1,1,1,3),
  col3=c(1,1,0,0,0),
  col4=c(1,0,0,0,0),
  col5=c(1,0,1,1,1)
)

data2<-data.frame(
  'ID 1' = c(53265,"ARV_7362",76354,"IND_2622","CHG_9762"),
  sector = c(3,3,1,2,5),
  name=c("nhug","hugy","mjuk","ghtr","kuld"),
  'Enternal code'=c(1,1,1,1,3),
  col3=c(1,1,0,0,0),
  col4=c(1,0,0,0,0),
  col5=c(1,0,1,1,1)
)
data2 %>% mutate(
  duplicated = factor(if_else(`ID 1` %in% 
                                pull(data1, `ID 1`),
                              1, 
                              0)))
```

now i am looking for a function to mutate my one data frame (data2) like. if I give column names of data1 and data2 to find if the values or string already exist in other data and mutate a new column to 1,0 for true and false.
the function would be like

func(data1 = "name",data2="name",mutated_com="name_exist")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, you can write this function as :

```
func <- function(data1, data2, data1col, data2col, newcol) {
  data2[[newcol]] <- factor(as.integer(data2[[data2col]] %in% data1[[data1col]]))
  data2
}
```

and can call it as :

```
func(data1, data2, 'name', 'name', 'duplicate')
```

This will create a column named `duplicate` in `data2` giving 1 where the name in `df2` is also present in `name` of `df1` and 0 otherwise.

---

Using `dplyr` syntax the above can be written as :

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

func <- function(data1, data2, data1col, data2col, newcol) {
  data2 %>% 
       mutate(!!newcol := factor(as.integer(.data[[data2col]] %in% 
                                  data1[[data1col]])))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inner_join (from dplyr) to determine the overlap between the two dataframes. To use all columns (if both dataframes have the same column names) you do not have to specify the 'by' argument.

You can then add a column 'duplicated' and join back to the original dataframe (df1 or df2) to get the desired result.

```
overlap <- data1 %>% 
  inner_join(data2) %>% 
  mutate(duplicated = 1)

data1 %>% #or data2
  left_join(overlap) %>% 
  mutate(duplicated = ifelse(is.na(duplicated),0,1))
```